# cannot get id of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the ID of the event targets parents parent, however it comes back as undefined, but I know for a fact the ID does exist as I have used firebug to confirm this.

Here is my html markup:

```
<div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle" id="chart"></div>
        <div class="overlayed" data-render="" data-chartType="" data-devID="" data-metricType="" data-refresh="30000" data-title="" data-subtitle=""
                    data-yAxis="" data-tooltip="" data-lineWidth="0.5" data-timeWindow="10">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons chart-edit" style="padding-right: 10px"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my javascript/jquery for trying to get the id

```
$('.overlayed').on('click', '.glyphicon-pencil', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("what is going on!");
    //hold the overlayed element for later use
    var overlayedData = $(this);
    var chartID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

    $('#editWidgetModal').modal('toggle');
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: Include your HTML please.

Comment: Have you tried `this.parentNode.parentNode.id`?

Comment: Sorry I did add it but didn't seem to show up

Comment: Is the `.overlayed` element in the DOM when it loads, or is it dynamically added?

Comment: I don't see any id to the parent's parent element

Comment: why don't you add FIDDLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parent().parent()` of `.glyphicon-pencil` is the `.grid-stack-item` element, which has no `id`. I assume you're attempting to target the `#chart` element, seen as it's the only one with an `id` in your HTML sample. If this is the case, your code fails as that element is a *sibling* of the parent element. In which case you can use `prev()` to get it. Try this:

```
var chartID = $(this).parent().prev().prop('id');
```

Or:

```
var chartID = $(this).closest('.overlayed').prev().prop('id');
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sadkad5t/)

Comment: I thought the parent of .glyphicon-pencil was .overlayed, but I will give this a try

Comment: It is, but you're trying to get the `id` from `#chart`, which is a sibling to `.overlayed`

Comment: No problem, glad to help.